# @parcel/optimizer-swc: 'const' declarations must be initialized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, parcel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgTz5.png)

I am currently working on a React web app using Parcel as the bundler. While developing, I have not encountered any issues, and the application runs smoothly with **`npm start`**. However, when I attempt to build the project using **`npm run build`**, I encounter an error that states "'const' declarations must be initialized." The error message is as follows:

```
plaintextCopy code
@parcel/optimizer-swc: 'const' declarations must be initialized 
19227 
| > 19228 
| > 
| ^ 19229 
| const $e73bf42412feb220$var$Grocery = /*#__PURE__*/ (0, $acw62.lazy)(()=>(parcelRequire( 19230 |
```

**Issue:** The error seems to be related to a **`const`** declaration that lacks initialization during the build process. Strangely, the application works perfectly when running locally with **`npm start`**.

**Attempts to Resolve:** I have tried several methods to resolve the issue, including:

1. Ensuring all **`const`** declarations have proper initializations.
2. Verifying that the code runs without errors using **`npm start`**.
3. Checking for any specific dependencies or configurations related to the build process.
4. Reviewing the Parcel documentation and community forums for similar issues.

**Request for Help:** Despite these efforts, I have been unable to pinpoint the root cause of the error during the build process. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights into resolving this specific issue with Parcel, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar error after installing the `sharp` package. I'm using parcel to build a react app:

```
@parcel/optimizer-swc: 'const' declarations must be initialized

  /home/admin/framimg/node_modules/sharp/lib/libvips.js:42:0
    41 | 
  > 42 | const runtimePlatformArch = () => `${process.platform}${run
  >    | ^
    43 | 
    44 | /* istanbul ignore next */
```

I don't see any problem with the line causing the error...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Parcel 2 and Vue 3.

I had in the main js file:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

import { Quasar } from 'quasar';

import app from './application/app';
import appRoutes from './application/app-routes';

const app = createApp(app);

app.use(createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes: appRoutes
}));

app.use(VueResource);

app.use(Quasar);

app.mount('#app');

export default app;
```

After change to this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

import { Quasar } from 'quasar';

import app from './application/app';
import appRoutes from './application/app-routes';

export default createApp(app)
    .use(createRouter({
        history: createWebHashHistory(),
        routes: appRoutes
    }))
    .use(VueResource)
    .use(Quasar)
    .mount('#app');
```

Error has gone.